# API does not list newly created folders

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using the Google Drive API V3. I was trying to list files and folders from a pre-existing folder. Earlier this folder consisted only files. The listing returned all the files. Then when I created 2 new folders. I am unable to find these two folders.

Shown below is my C# method:

```
        public void FindFiles(FindFilesParam p)
        {
            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = _service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = p.PageSize;
            //listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
            //listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";
            //listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, md5Checksum, createdTime, modifiedTime, size)";
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(*)";
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.FolderId))
                listRequest.Q = $@"('{p.FolderId}' in parents)";
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList fileList = listRequest.Execute();
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileList.NextPageToken))
            {
                listRequest.PageToken = fileList.NextPageToken;
                fileList = listRequest.Execute();
                if (FindFilesReturnedPage != null)
                {
                    var e = new FindFilesReturnedPageEventArgs(
                        fileList.Files, p.RelativePath);
                    FindFilesReturnedPage(this, e);
                    if (e.Cancel)
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (FindFilesFinished != null)
                FindFilesFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    public class FindFilesParam
    {
        public FindFilesParam()
        {
            PageSize = 10;
        }

        public string FolderId { set; get; }
        public string RelativePath { set; get; }
        public int? PageSize { set; get; }
    }


// Calling this as follows:

FindFiles(new FindFilesParam()
{
    FolderId = "1hYcRWXaQcg1Noh06rPCouIgIl5TZ8BWP",
    RelativePath = string.Empty
});
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your authentication code. and the code you are using to create the files.

Comment: @DalmTo, I have about more than a thousand files/folder in this drive. My program lists only about 810 of these files. So IMHO it's not an authentication issue. Also, I am simply dragging and dropping files from my windows explorer into Google Drive. My application is only doing the listing of files/folders.

Comment: Then do a full file.list and remove your q and look for it there. If your not seeing it and  wont post your authorization code then there is really no way of knowing if the current user has access to the folder you are looking for.

Comment: also try $"'{p.FolderId} in parents";   Testing out the Q with try me might help as well https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list.   I suspect you are looking for it in the wrong directory.

Comment: Thank you all, I got it working after applying changes suggested by Andres Duarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the first page of files list, the code at the beginning of the `while` it's overriding the first files list page which is made outside the while.

Use this piece of code instead to ensure you'll use both the first and last files list pages:

```
 Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList fileList = listRequest.Execute();
 while (true) {
     .......
     //Print or use files list
     ........

     //Break loop if there's no NextPageToken
     if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileList.NextPageToken)) break;

     listRequest.PageToken = fileList.NextPageToken;
     fileList = listRequest.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Great no worries! If it helped you please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)